# I want to know what the method is. when a button is clicked, screen shows a little small option box

Tags: android, listview, methods, youtube

sorry that i couldnt upload a picture cuz not understanding of "need at least 10 reputations to upload an image"

anyway, when you use "Youtube" MOBILE application, 
you can see several videos shown on a screen arranged in a custom listview.
and in each item of the listview, there are "three-circled" button at the right side of the item(row).

when you click that button, it appers a small option choosing box.

I want to know what method that small option choosing box implemented. 
are there any references or any method name for that?

Comment: Now you have 10 reputation ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a simple class for that.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html

and if you're going to be compatible with really really old versions of Android you use the version from the compatibility library.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html

to show this PopupMenu it's a simple code too:

```
PopupMenu p = PopupMenu(context, theViewThatWasClicked);
p.inflate(R.menu.popup_options); // the options to show
p.setOnMenuItemClickListener(listener); // you have to create this listener somewhere
p.show();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! i didn't know it was called 'popup' stuff